# Can we unsubscribe from recurring payment via passing subscribe id on link

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

```
<form name="myform" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <div id="other_element"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $adminpaypal; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Monthly Subscription">
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo $paypal_notify; ?>" id="payment-notify" />
    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <input name="return" value="<?php echo $paypal_return; ?>" type="hidden"> 
    <input type="image" src="" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

I have created form of paypal for monthly subscription. After subscription, I am getting "subscription id". Now I am working on making unsubscribe button.Is it possible to make unsubscribe button via passing subscription id on link ?

Answer (score 0):

If you created your subscription using **subscription button creator** then you can follow these steps.

When you go to your saved buttons, click on "action"-->"view code". At the bottom, under your code, there is a "create unsubscribe button" option.

Create the button and copy the code. Paste it in your web app. You are good to go.

Here is the button creator code with hidden values---

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"> //custom variable. You can access it like $_POST['cmd'] when you call listener (IPN)
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="*********">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['id']; ?>">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

And here is the code for unsubscribe button. When you will create unsubscribe button, it will generate same code. Just ****** will be replaced by some value.

```
<a HREF="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_subscr-find&alias=*******">
    <img SRC="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_unsubscribe_LG.gif" BORDER="0">
</a>
```

Comment: No,Actually, I want to send some more information like user_id etc with the form. So that is only possible to make custom form like I have.

Comment: @Pankaj Sharma No. You have wrong info. You can send user_id through subscri button code too. Just like you are sending hidden fields right now. Smthing Like this <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>">

Comment: Can you share some piece of code to see that how you pass hidden value with button generator ?

Comment: @PankajSharma  I added and explained the code in my first answer only.

Comment: @user38314445 Where we will setup notify_url in this code ?